# Referencing a Published WCF Service

Tags: wcf, iis, publish

I have followed "Walkthrough: Creating and Accessing WCF Services" from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386386.aspx to create a WCF Service Library. I tested it in WCF Test Client. Then in another desktop application (let's call it A) that eventually I would like to use this WCF I added the Service Reference that WCF Test Client gives

```
http://localhost:8733/...
```

and that worked too.

Now, I am in the process of publishing and using the published version's service reference. Here is what I did, I published the WCF Service Library by

1. right-clicking the solution
2. Choosing Publish
3. clicking ...
4. Choosing File System and typing

   \mywebaddress.example.com\wwwroot\myWCFService

Looks like the publish is successful, because by navigating to

```
\\mywebaddress.example.com\wwwroot\myWCFService
```

in a file browser, I see that Web.config, .svc and bin folder are created.

Now, I am trying to refer to this published version from my desktop application A. I am not certain what options I'm supposed to choose

Here is what I have tried:

1. Choose Add Service Reference in the desktop application A,
2. I tried

   \mywebaddress.example.com\wwwroot\myWCFService

in the Address field of Add Service Reference, Pressed Go and received the error An error (Details) occurred while attempting to find services at

```
\\mywebaddress.example.com\wwwroot\myWCFService.
```

When clicking on Details, I get There was an error downloading

```
\\mywebaddress.example.com\wwwroot\myWCFService
```

Access to the path

```
\\mywebaddress.example.com\wwwroot\myWCFService
```

is denied.

If the service is defined in the current solution, try building the solution and adding the service reference again.

Alternatively, I tried Advanced option from Add Service Reference and from there Add Web Reference... and in the URL field typed

```
http://www.example.com/myWCFService/
```

then when pressing the arrow button I get 401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials.

You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied. and in the Web services found at this URL: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: discoveryError & mexError.

Th latter error was when in the IIS setting I had Anonymous Authentication Disabled. After enabling Anonymous Authentication the error becomes:

403 - Forbidden: Access is denied.
You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied.

Web services found at this URL: There was an error downloading

http://www.example.com/wcfservice/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/$metadata

The request failed with HTTP status 404: Not Found.

Comment: I notice you have IIS in your tags, but not in your question. What does this have to do with IIS?

Comment: I'm not sure either. But my intention is to publish this WCF in IIS and by publishing in the File System that I mentioned, it does show up in the IIS. I'm not very expert in IIS, so I'm not sure how it's showing in the IIS even though I am choosing the file system for publishing.

Comment: You don't have to be an expert in IIS to know that the file system is not IIS.

Comment: And, to be honest, you don't have to be an expert to Google "[publish asp.net web site](https://www.google.com/search?q=publish%20asp.net%20web%20site&rct=j)".

Comment: I have published a Web Service in IIS and I am using it with no problem in iOS, Android, and Desktop application. Just recently decided to convert the Web Service to WCF and the story above...

Comment: So, what happens when you publish to IIS? Just like you did the ASMX web service? You should be able to do the WCF web service the same way.

Comment: Web Service and WCF give me different publish options, so it's hard to do the same thing that I was doing for Web Service on WCF or I don't know how. For Web Service I would choose Web Deploy Package as Publish method, then move the package to my IIS server and run .cmd file to deploy the package in the IIS. I just don't see this option in the Publish menu of WCF and as far as IIS it only has Local IIS. That's why I chose File System which apparently works, i.e., puts the files in my IIS server but then I get the errors that I mentioned in my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I just now published a WCF Service Library project with Visual Studio 2013, I was offered the options for file system, Local IIS, and FTP Site. When I choose "Local IIS", it shows me both IIS Express and my local full IIS.

I just published to IIS by selecting "Default Web Site" and clicking the "Create Web Application" button in the tooolbar. I named the application, clicked "Open", then clicked "Publish" on the main publish dialog.

This published a bin folder with the service DLL and other libraries it needed, a web.config, and a .svc file. I was able to browse to the .svc file with no problem. I was even able to add it as a service reference to another project.

If you are always going to host your services in IIS, and if you don't need to keep a clean separation of layers (perhaps you're only writing a few, simple services), then I recommend you use the "WCF Service Application" template instead. This creates a Web project in which to host the services, as well as the .svc and .cs files necessary for the services themselves. That's more like the only option that was available for ASMX web services.

Comment: Thanks a lot John! I will try this out later on and update this post accordingly.

Comment: The IIS that I would like to publish this WCF Service to is not located on the same server as the development environment. Would Local IIS publish option be feasible in this case? I don't think so.

Comment: Take a look at my final paragraph.

Comment: That's what I said I'm gonna try later on. Thanks again.

Comment: I ended up doing what you suggested in the final paragraph and since it was just like you suggested very similar to the way I used to do in WSDL Web Service, it worked fine. Thanks a lot!